# Setting the min and max bounds for a random distribution class member, at run-time?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I have a C++ uniform distribution object. However, it is a class member, not on the stack (like every example seems to be).

I would like to set the upper and lower bounds of the distribution after reading config at run-time.

I saw there is a reset() member, but this doesn't allow passing a min and max.

What's the best way change the upper and lower bounds after construction? Should I just create one on the stack and assign it to my class member?

Comment: Why can't you construct the object after you read the configuration file?

Comment: Why can't you set the `param` via, for example, [`std::uniform_int_distribution<IntType>::param`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/param)? As in: `dis.param (std::uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type (min, max));`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Did not know about param

Comment: @user997112 But it is listed in the documentation, of, for example [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The method name "param()" did not stand out as much as "reset()"

Comment: @user997112 For me "_gets or sets the distribution parameter object_" stood out, as something, that could change the internal properties of an object. I don't look only at the names of methods, when looking at documentation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm happy for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reassign it:

```
dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(min, max);
```